# sed string replacement for exact match containing /

Tags: linux, shell-script, sed, search

I am trying to use sed to search for the occurrence of an exact string that contains / in it. Below is the approach I am trying, but without luck.

```
input_string="/path /path1 /path2"
search_string="/path"
input_string=echo $input_string | sed "s#\b$search_string\b##g"
```

But when I run these sequence of commands, I am still input_string to contain the value "/path /path1 /path2" instead of "/path1 /path2"

I even tried `input_string=echo $input_string | sed "s#\<$search_string\>##g"` but without any luck

I am using RHEL6.5 and running this command from shell.

Comment: What shell is this? AFAIK an assignment like `input_string=echo blah` isn't legal (you need a command substitution like `$( ... )` or backticks. Aside from that, I suspect the issue is that `/` is a non-word character, so that there is no word boundary *before* it - do you get the desired result if you remove the initial `\b`? FYI you may be able to do what you want more simply using shell parameter substitution.

Comment: I suppose input_string is set with input_string=$( ), beside there is no leading blank in your test case.

Comment: No shell handy, but I assume that with `"...\b..."` the shell will already try to parse that as an escape sequence, so sed doesn't even see it. Do you mind trying if `"...\\b..."` works better?

Comment: **echo ${input_string##$search_string}**  will strip leading $search_string (but not first space, hence I didn't post as answer).

Comment: @Archemar how about `${input_string##$search_string }`?

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is the `/` in the pattern in `$search_string`.

Since `/` is not an alphanumeric character, it's not considered a "word".  This means that the pattern `\</path\>` would not match `/path` since there is no word boundary before the `/`.

Change the search string to `/path\>` (i.e. `s##$search_string\>##g`) instead, or use `/path[^0-9]`, or, with these specific input data and search string, you could simply use `s#$search_string ##g` as the substitution.

Answer (score 3):

## short answer

use this command to get what you want :

`input_string=$(echo $input_string | sed "s#$search_string\b##g")`

## Long answer

#### Why `sed` isn't replacing

`\b` means a word boundary, and here is it's definition :

> The metacharacter \b is an anchor like the caret and the dollar sign. It matches at a position that is called a "word boundary". This match is zero-length.
>
> There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:
>
> - Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
> - After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
> - Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

Found it [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). So, the first character of your `search_string` is a `/`, and it seems that `sed` can't find a word boundary because of the first rule (because the `/` isn't a word character).

#### Why the result isn't stored in `input_string`

you need to first execute the two commands (`echo` and `sed`), then store the result in the variable `input_string`. To do this, put the two commands inside `$()`. This will make them execute and return the result to your variable (see the command in the **short answer**).

I know it's not a complete answer, but that's all I got.

Answer (score 0):

Exact word matching in `sed` is tricky, especially if you want to write a portable solution, or if your definition of a "word" contains special characters other than `_` (as in your situation). The best way I have found to do this is to consider all 4 cases where a word might appear in a line of input:

1. At the beginning
2. At the end
3. At both the beginning and the end (occupying the entire line)
4. In the middle somewhere

If your definition of a word is simply a sequence of non-whitespace characters, then the following solution should work for you (tested):

`` _s='[  ]' # contains a space and a literal tab character (CTRL-V + TAB)
input_string=`echo "$input_string" | sed \
-e "s|^$search_string\\($_s\\)|\\1|g" \
-e "s|\\($_s\\)$search_string$|\\1|g" \
-e "s|^$search_string$||g" \
-e "s|\\($_s\\)$search_string\\($_s\\)|\\1\\2|g"` ``

Note that I have chosen `|` as the delimiter instead of `#`. This is because `#` can show up in file names (for example, [Emacs auto-save files](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Auto-Save-Files.html)) while `|` is reserved, at least on Linux. Also note that the output will contain the whitespace character(s) surrounding each instance of `$search_string`. If you would rather omit the whitespace, you can use this instead (tested):

`` _s='[  ]' # contains a space and a literal tab character (CTRL-V + TAB)
input_string=`echo "$input_string" | sed \
-e "s|^$_s*$search_string$_s\\{1,\\}||g" \
-e "s|$_s\\{1,\\}$search_string$_s*$||g" \
-e "s|^$search_string$||g" \
-e "s|\\($_s\\)$search_string$_s\\{1,\\}|\\1|g"` ``

That last expression looks a little different, and for good reason -- you don't want to remove whitespace on both sides of `$search_string` once you've gotten this far in processing the input line, because in doing so, you would remove whitespace between unmatched words on either side of `$search_string`, which would smoosh them together.

**Final notes:**

- You might be able to get away with omitting some of the `g` modifiers in
  the `sed` expressions, but it doesn't hurt to leave them in.
- It probably goes without saying, but if your `$search_string` is a path,
  it cannot contain any space.